# Background Service stops working after sc.exe start

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, windows-services, .net-6.0, background-service

I'm writing code for background service which is designed to collect data by OPC UA protocol. Service worked as intended, before I desided to refactor in order to conform to modern patterns (DI).

Before refactor the main part of the service (while loop routine), I tried to refactor my FileLogger to be used as a service, so as it is constructor-injected to my hosted service.

The problem arose when I try to register services in container. Firstly I hardcoded the path to log directory (first iteration of worker used `@$"{System.AppContext.BaseDirectory}\logs"` path) when passing it to the constructor but it failed to start.

I put a block of code into `StartAsync` method:

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new("path to file", true)) {
  await writer.WriteLineAsync(message);
}
```

There is no file created and my service is out of game. It seems like `StartAsync` isn't started at all and unhandled exception is thrown on host creation.

The structure of the file logging service:

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace OpcService.Services;

internal interface IOpcLogger
{
  Task<bool> AppendMessage(string message, DateTime timestamp);

  Task<bool> AppendMessageList(List<string> messages, DateTime timestamp);

  bool DeleteMessagesBeforeToday(byte daysBeforeToday);
}

internal class OpcFileLogger : IOpcLogger
{
  private const string TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = "HH:mm:ss"; 
  
  public string MessageDirectory { get; }
  
  public OpcFileLogger(string messageDirectory) 
    => MessageDirectory = (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(messageDirectory)) 
      ? messageDirectory
      : throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(messageDirectory)} cannot be null/empty/whitespace.");

  public async Task<bool> AppendMessage(string message, DateTime timestamp)
  {
    try {
      if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message)) {
        throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(message)} cannot be null/empty/whitespace.", nameof(message));
      }
      if (!Directory.Exists(MessageDirectory)) {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(MessageDirectory);
      }
      message = $"[{timestamp.ToString(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT)}] {message}";
      using (StreamWriter writer = new(@$"{MessageDirectory}\{timestamp.ToString("ddMMyyyy")}.txt", true)) {
        await writer.WriteLineAsync(message);
      }
      return true;
    } catch {  
      return false;
    }
  }
  // other methods
}
```

Dependent class:

```
internal class OpcUaWorker : BackgroundService 
{
  private WorkerSettings? ServiceSettings { get; set; }

  private readonly IOpcLogger _opcLogger; 

  private string WorkerFilePath { get; } = @$"{System.AppContext.BaseDirectory}\worker.json";

  private string DBConfigFilePath { get; } = @$"{System.AppContext.BaseDirectory}\db.config";

  // private string LogsDirectoryPath { get; } = @$"{System.AppContext.BaseDirectory}\logs";

  public OpcUaWorker(IOpcLogger opcLogger) 
    => _opcLogger = opcLogger;

  protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
  {
    // opc session
  }

  public override async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
  {
    await _opcLogger.AppendMessage("Module is starting...\n", DateTime.Now);
    await base.StartAsync(stoppingToken);
  }

  public override async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken) 
  {
    await _opcLogger.AppendMessage("Module is stopping...\n", DateTime.Now);
    await base.StopAsync(stoppingToken); 
  }
}
```

Injector routine:

```
using OpcService;
using OpcService.Services;

IHost host = Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
  .UseWindowsService()
  .ConfigureServices(services => {
    services.AddSingleton<IOpcLogger, OpcFileLogger>(provider => new OpcFileLogger(@"d:\Projects\OpcUaWorker\logs"));
    services.AddHostedService<OpcUaWorker>();
  })
  .Build();
await host.RunAsync();
```

Only when use `services.AddSingleton<IOpcLogger, OpcFileLogger>();` and don't use parameterised constructor (`public string MessageDirectory { get; } = @"d:\Projects\OpcUaWorker\logs";`), it works.

As recommended in comments, I find the following error record in Event View:

```
Application: OpcUaWorker.exe
CoreCLR Version: 6.0.1122.52304
.NET Version: 6.0.11
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'OpcService.Services.IOpcLogger' while attempting to activate 'OpcService.OpcUaWorker'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(ServiceIdentifier serviceIdentifier, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
```

Comment: _"and unhandled exception is thrown on host creation"_ - care to share that with us? Why would you omit the one most important piece of information you have about the error you are facing?

Comment: If I knew, I would mention it here. cmd doesn't show error. When starting from services.msc it just stops after launching.

Comment: Because you catch and swallow. (Well, you return `false`, which doesn't seem to have any effect) Catch the actual exception _and at least log it out_. Then you can see what's happening.

Comment: @Fildor I wrote in post that I used try catch in `StartAsync`. I had also used it in `ExecuteAsync` before that attempt.  Nothing is logged.

Comment: I can only comment on the code I see. So, _if_ there is an error, first step is to find out, where to catch it to get details. Without that, it's hard to suggest improvements. Could be a whole range of things. File/Path permission issues for example ... but that's all guesses until we can see an error message. Idea: Did you have a look into Windows Event Logs?

Comment: That looks like a DI problem, indeed. Which is strange because it looks ok to me ...

Comment: For a test: what happens, when (in your IDE) you comment out `await host.RunAsync();` and instead do `var test = host.Services.GetRequiredService<IOpcLogger>();` ? And then hit Debug-Run?

Comment: @Fildor vscode says: 'messageDirectory cannot be null/empty/whitespace.' I passed string with the path, didn't I? Moreover: 'Cannot obtain value of local or argument as it is not available at this instruction pointer, possibly because it has been optimized away'

Comment: @Fildor it looks like nothing is passed to constructor, but is it possible?

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. That would mean it ignored the Factory configuration ( `(provider => new OpcFileLogger(@"d:\Projects\OpcUaWorker\logs"));` ) It's not obvious to me why it would do that.

Comment: @Fildor I found the answer. Ternary operator in constructor: exception should be thrown when empty not when argument is provided. Just swapped the operands. I would like to know one last thing: can I use `System.AppContext.BaseDirectory` as argument on injection phase?

Comment: Ooooh, totally missed that. Good catch! _"can I use System.AppContext.BaseDirectory as argument on injection phase?"_ - Give it a try. I would guess you can, but you'll see it rather quickly if you cannot :)

Comment: @Fildor, Already done that. Should I close the question? Although the reason of the issues was simple, but you tell me where to search (event viewer) + I didn't use to know that  I could run BackgroundService project in debug mode. Maybe, it will of help for someone in future? And I highly appreciate your work dedicated to my post.

Comment: Up to you. Could be helpful to write an answer with what caused the problem and how you found out. Comments can (and probably will) be deleted, so they won't sufficiently excuse keeping a Q that is basically caused by a "typo" kind of error. But it is welcomed to answer your own question, when you solved it yourself. - Which you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made up the solution with the help of recommendation in the comment section by looking at Event Viewer. After I tried to debug my code using VSCode without `await host.RunAsync();` (another tip from the same user), I realised that my object wasn't initalized with correct argument, so taking look at `OpcUaWorker` constructor led me to:

```
public OpcFileLogger(string messageDirectory) 
    => MessageDirectory = (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(messageDirectory)) 
      ? throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(messageDirectory)} cannot be null/empty/whitespace.")
      : messageDirectory;
```